# How to use current experimental pcl together with ROS Fuerte?

Tags: ros, pcl, svn, ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

what is the easiest way to use the current **experimental** version of the PCL together with ROS Fuerte (which includes PCL 1.5 by default)? There are some features I would like to use which aren't available in version 1.5.

I found [this directory](http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-fuerte-pcl/) but I don't know what these files are for, since there is no official PCL 1.5.**2**.

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36837/how-to-use-current-experimental-pcl-together-with-ros-fuerte?/) by [ph4nt0m](https://answers.ros.org/users/1315/ph4nt0m/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2012-06-19

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Fuerte uses pcl 1.5 as default.
This link in mailing list could be of help:  http://code.ros.org/lurker/message/20120618.220556.be95ed89.en.html

Your question is answered by Bhaskara. I am reproducing it here

```
We've been using pcl trunk with fuerte: 
https://bitbucket.org/bhaskara/perception_pcl_fuerte_unstable 

It puts the pcl trunk code into a 'pcl16' namespace, so that it can 
coexist with fuerte's pcl 1.5. Using it basically involves replacing 
the pcl and pcl_ros namespaces with pcl16 and pcl16_ros respectively. 
- Bhaskara
```

---

Originally posted by [prince](https://answers.ros.org/users/939/prince/) with karma: 660 on 2012-06-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ph4nt0m](https://answers.ros.org/users/1315/ph4nt0m/) on 2012-06-20**:
Thank you! How does this work? I cloned the git repository, but it doesn't contain the PCL trunk code, so I assume I have to merge them somehow. But how can this package change the c++ namespace to "pcl16" if it does not even contain the (modified) pcl header files?

**Comment by [prince](https://answers.ros.org/users/939/prince/) on 2012-06-20**:
Code is present in repo. I just checked. Can you try again?

**Comment by [ph4nt0m](https://answers.ros.org/users/1315/ph4nt0m/) on 2012-06-20**:
I used "hg clone [https://bitbucket.org/bhaskara/perception_pcl_fuerte_unstable"](https://bitbucket.org/bhaskara/perception_pcl_fuerte_unstable%22), but I doesn't actually contain the pcl header and source files, so I think I have to get these from http://svn.pointclouds.org/pcl/trunk and merge them with perception_pcl_fuerte_unstable in some way!?

**Comment by [bhaskara](https://answers.ros.org/users/95/bhaskara/) on 2012-06-20**:
No, you don't have to do that.  Just clone this repo somewhere in your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH, then do rosmake pcl16_ros.  pcl will be checked out during the build process (see pcl16/Makefile).

**Comment by [ph4nt0m](https://answers.ros.org/users/1315/ph4nt0m/) on 2012-06-20**:
I did exactly what you said, but unfortunately when it comes to executing pcl16/Makefile, I get "CMake Error: The source directory "~/workspace/perception_pcl_fuerte_unstable/pcl16/build/pcl_trunk" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt". Apparently, the pcl trunk is not checked out at all. :(

**Comment by [bhaskara](https://answers.ros.org/users/95/bhaskara/) on 2012-06-20**:
You're right — there was an error in the makefile that caused it to not work on a fresh install.  I've pushed a fix; can you try it now?

**Comment by [ph4nt0m](https://answers.ros.org/users/1315/ph4nt0m/) on 2012-06-20**:
Thanks! The build dir in pcl16 had to be deleted in order for the respective makefile target to be executed. Thank you for fixing this :) Just one further question: What would be the best way to upgrade to a new trunk? Just change the revision in the Makefile and recompile or to do a fresh install?

**Comment by [bhaskara](https://answers.ros.org/users/95/bhaskara/) on 2012-06-20**:
I don't believe changing the revision will trigger a new build. You'll have to do an rm -rf build in the pcl16 directory as well.  It would be nice to be able to svn update pcl and just remake the changed bits, but the problem is that we're patching pretty much all the files after checking them out.

**Comment by [ZsurzsaLaszlo](https://answers.ros.org/users/2208/zsurzsalaszlo/) on 2013-06-14**:
Give me error: